# PDF Reader that can do handwritten annotations?

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a PDF reader that allows to add hand-written annotations to a pdf file using the touchscreen of my convertible laptop.

I've tried plenty, none seems really satisfying ... maybe someone knows a hidden gem that I haven't found yet ? Here's what I tried:

- **Xournal++** somehow crashes on my machine on startup (doesn't work well with PipeWire), also the fact that it doesn't automatically store the annotations to the PDF is inconvenient. Exporting to a PDF can easily lead to confusion and multiple files flying around, which is especially annoying if you sync scholary articles using Zotero. Also, I need a PDF Reader, not a full-fledged note taking solution with voice recorder and what not.
- **Okular** is the one I'm currently using, but to be honest the "Freehand Line" feature is terrible, slow and basically unusable for handwriting.

I haven't tried Foxit yet, is it any good ?

Maybe someone has a hint here ...

Best,
N

Comment: Currently using this feature with okular (21.08.3) under kde plasma 5.23.5 & kde frameworks 5.90.0 + qt 5.15.2 + linux kernel 5.4 … **core 2** powered and just not experiencing **any** response time / usability problem. I'd presume that something else is going wrong in your config.

Comment: Ok, and the lines are smooth ? In my case they're not following the stylus at all ... not sure where to look ...

Comment: Do you experience similar problems when, instead of your stylus, use the mouse ?

Comment: Hmm with the mouse it still lags behind at times ...

Comment: Several apps dedicated to screenshots also enable the user to annotate. If running kde-plasma, it will be *spectacle*, then click on the Annotate button. Do you experience similar troubles ?

Comment: Hmm I tried old Xournal and OpenBoard, and I remember them being way smoother in general ...